# Java: Many-to-one bidirectional lookup

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have data in a many-to-one relationship. I'd like to be able to lookup data from both directions. An example:

```
0 : a
1 : b
2 : b
3 : b
4 : c

get(0) --> a
get(1) --> b
get(a) --> 0
get(b) --> (1:3)
```

Does this make sense? Is it possible?

Comment: it does not make sense. it is possible

Comment: Are the left and right side items of the same type, or different types?

Comment: There are certainly situations where this can be useful, and it is very much possible. What problems are you having with creating a data structure that can do this? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Yes and no. The ultimate data types are different -- keystrokes to final characters. However, if I can just map an index to an index (int to int) I'll be fine.

Comment: You could use a `BiMap<String, List<Integer>>` (BiMap is part of guava)

Comment: But how would I look up one of those Integers to find the String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible. Here is a fragment of code for adding items:

```
Map<Integer,String> forwardMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Set<Integer>> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();

void add(Integer x, String y) {
    forwardMap.put(x, y);
    if (!reverseMap.containsKey(y))
        reverseMap.put(y, new HashSet<Integer>());
    reverseMap.get(y).add(x);
}
```

Footnote: Apache Commons has BidiMap and Google Guava has BiMap, but these appear to be one-to-one maps, disallowing the many-to-one case asked in the question.

Comment: I like this idea. I'm going to play around with it.

Comment: +1 In general, specialized collections are often easy to build by combining two or more java.util collections with wrapper code that exposes the required behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 2 hahsmaps.  Lets say your "one" is of type Integer and "many" is of type String for simplicity.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> intToString = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> stringToInt= new HashMap<>();
```

funciton for linking elements:

```
public void linkElements(Integer i, String s){
  intToString.add(i,s);
  stringToInt.get(s).add(i);
}
```

getting values would be like this:

```
intToString.get(0);    // returns "a"
stringToInt.get("b");  // returns a set {1,2,3}
```

Comment: Hello. This is a duplicate of my answer, and it doesn't add value to the discussion

Comment: I typed it at the same time as you.  You just type faster apparently -- still gave yours the upvote.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, you need to add stuff to your `stringToInt` map, or else the `get(s)` will always return `null`.

Comment: Thanks @aguibert. I definitely took ideas from your answer, as well.

Answer (score -1):

yes use JPA(Java Persistence API) it will give you the ability to make @OneToMany and in the child it will give you List with @ManyToOne basically it will be reference to property to your patent property. Example

```
public class Table1{
    @Id 
    int id ; 
    @OneToMany 
    List<Table2> ls ; 

   // getter and setter ...
}

public class Table2{
        @Id 
        int id ; 
        @ManyToOne 
        Table1 t1 ; 

       // getter and setter ...
    }
```

hopefully this help you

Comment: This isn't a DB question, they are just wondering how to do this with JavaSE.